# Why is Jsp parsing "<="?

Tags: jsp

I have the following code in a jsp:

```
<div ng-show="controller.var1 <= 1 && controller.var2 > 0">
```

The output is:

```
<div ng-show="controller.var1  0">
```

I know "<%" and friends are special JSP syntax, but I've never seen "<=" have an impact before. It doesn't matter where I put a "<=" in the page - everything after it is ignored up to and including the next ">"

Any ideas what might be going on? I'm baffled.

Comment: Looks like you want to use EL `${controller.var1 <= 1 && controller.var2 > 0}` or `${controller.var1 le 1 and controller.var2 gt 0}`.

Comment: what is `ng-show` attribute here?

Comment: Please share minimal testable code. There is no ending tag.

Comment: @Tiny - No. I want the text to be returned from the server exactly as it is here. I'm confused as to why any changes are happening at all.

Comment: @Braj - This is the minimal code. I would expect that, were I to put this in a JSP, it would be returned to the browser exactly as is. For some reason, that's not happening. The ng-show is an angular thing, but that's client side and not relevant to the problem I'm having :/

Answer (score 1):

`<=` is not a JSP scriplet or expression.

`<= 1 && controller.var2 >` (this <> block is conflicted with the html tags now since it is not evaluated by JSP) is "ignored" by your browser or `AngularJS` (since there is `ng-show`, I guess you are using `AngularJS`) rendering.

That is why the output is `controller.var1` and `0`.

Comment: Well, that's what I initially thought, but if I use just "<" instead of "<=" in the expression, it prints the entire expression correctly.

Comment: It's also not an issue with how the browser or angular interprets it - the middle part of the expression is missing in the text returned from the server before it gets to the browser.